# Getting Indefinite Spinner for Docusign Embedded Focus View

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I'm trying to build a custom element to put a focused view of a docusign document in an elm app. It almost works, but in the app, I'm just getting an infinite spinner and a "powered by docusign" logo in the bottom right.

I wonder if the issue is upstream, as when I try to just paste the embed url in the browser directly, it just goes straight to the redirect url. Not sure where to look to figure out what's going on.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-focused-view/

```
customElements.define('docusign-signature',
  class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    }

    connectedCallback() {
      console.log('Connected callback triggered');
      this.render();
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
      console.log(`Attribute changed: ${name}, Old value: ${oldValue}, New value: ${newValue}`);
      this.render();
    }

    static get observedAttributes() {
      return ['url', 'integration-key'];
    }

    render() {
      console.log('Render method called');

      const url = this.getAttribute('url');
      const integrationKey = this.getAttribute('integration-key');

      console.log('URL:', url);
      console.log('Integration Key:', integrationKey);

      if (!url || !integrationKey) {
        console.log('Missing required attributes');
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = 'Missing required attributes';
        return;
      }

      const style = document.createElement('style');
      style.textContent = `
        .docusign-agreement {
          width: 100%;
          height: 800px;
        }
      `;
      this.shadowRoot.appendChild(style);

      const agreementDiv = document.createElement('div');
      agreementDiv.className = 'docusign-agreement';
      agreementDiv.id = 'agreement';
      this.shadowRoot.appendChild(agreementDiv);

      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = 'https://js.docusign.com/bundle.js';
      script.onload = () => {
        console.log('DocuSign script loaded');
        window.DocuSign.loadDocuSign(integrationKey)
          .then((docusign) => {
            console.log('DocuSign loaded successfully');
            const signing = docusign.signing({
              url: url,
              displayFormat: 'focused',
              style: {
                branding: {
                  primaryButton: {
                    backgroundColor: '#333',
                    color: '#fff'
                  }
                },
                signingNavigationButton: {
                  finishText: 'You have finished the document! Hooray!',
                  position: 'bottom-center'            
                }
              }
            });
            
            signing.on('ready', (event) => {
              console.log('UI is rendered'); 
            });
            
            signing.on('sessionEnd', (event) => {
              console.log('sessionend', event);
            });
            
            signing.mount(this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#agreement'));
          })
          .catch((ex) => {
            console.error('Error loading DocuSign:', ex);
          });
      };
      this.shadowRoot.appendChild(script);
    }
  }
);
```

**EDIT**
Adding relevant HAR file content per question below

```
        "cache": {},
        "connection": "976400",
        "request": {
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/RasterizerImage.aspx?insession=1&ti=7e2359c830454567a88c60fe6b75ce97&p=5&d=150&pid=b1aff4b7-0888-4195-a695-d1cf983cb8b6&vm=false",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Accept",
              "value": "image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Encoding",
              "value": "gzip, deflate, br"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Language",
              "value": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
            },
            {
              "name": "Connection",
              "value": "keep-alive"
            },
            {
              "name": "Cookie",
              "value": "drift_aid=bdd6ff22-9e95-4fb8-b904-e904955798f1; driftt_aid=bdd6ff22-9e95-4fb8-b904-e904955798f1; drift_eid=84225428-aa42-4559-8614-f3c8befbbf90; pv=DA4DFE71_7801; ssid=deg4dob3hltz3vzaefbvqjim; MemberConsoleMobile=; __RequestVerificationToken_L1NpZ25pbmc1=AUg7xNmdsECMOXs8jueYqMkB0; DSSessionAttributes=EnvelopeId:7addcbc5-ffb4-4a25-a7f2-e092fc4f73ca,SenderAccountId:0a060a89-b542-4301-90b4-d45c7d5ef06e,RecipientAccountId:cccccccc-cccc-cccc-cccc-cccccccccccc,RecipientId:0e8a037b-5627-41d7-a5f5-9b2fa47b6e40"
            },
            {
              "name": "DNT",
              "value": "1"
            },
            {
              "name": "Host",
              "value": "demo.docusign.net"
            },
            {
              "name": "Referer",
              "value": "https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/?insession=1&ti=7e2359c830454567a88c60fe6b75ce97"
            },
            {
              "name": "Sec-Fetch-Dest",
              "value": "image"
            },
            {
              "name": "Sec-Fetch-Mode",
              "value": "no-cors"
            },
            {
              "name": "Sec-Fetch-Site",
              "value": "same-origin"
            },
            {
              "name": "User-Agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/107.0.0.0"
            },
            {
              "name": "sec-ch-ua",
              "value": "\"Not A(Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Opera GX\";v=\"107\", \"Chromium\";v=\"121\""
            },
            {
              "name": "sec-ch-ua-mobile",
              "value": "?0"
            },
            {
              "name": "sec-ch-ua-platform",
              "value": "\"macOS\""
            }
          ],
          "queryString": [
            {
              "name": "insession",
              "value": "1"
            },
            {
              "name": "ti",
              "value": "7e2359c830454567a88c60fe6b75ce97"
            },
            {
              "name": "p",
              "value": "5"
            },
            {
              "name": "d",
              "value": "150"
            },
            {
              "name": "pid",
              "value": "b1aff4b7-0888-4195-a695-d1cf983cb8b6"
            },
            {
              "name": "vm",
              "value": "false"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [
            {
              "name": "drift_aid",
              "value": "bdd6ff22-9e95-4fb8-b904-e904955798f1",
              "path": "/",
              "domain": ".docusign.net",
              "expires": "2025-04-11T00:46:52.772Z",
              "httpOnly": false,
              "secure": true,
              "sameSite": "None"
            },
            {
              "name": "driftt_aid",
              "value": "bdd6ff22-9e95-4fb8-b904-e904955798f1",
              "path": "/",
              "domain": ".docusign.net",
              "expires": "2025-04-11T00:46:52.772Z",
              "httpOnly": false,
              "secure": true,
              "sameSite": "None"
            },
            {
              "name": "drift_eid",
              "value": "84225428-aa42-4559-8614-f3c8befbbf90",
              "path": "/",
              "domain": ".docusign.net",
              "expires": "1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z",
              "httpOnly": false,
              "secure": true,
              "sameSite": "None"
            },
            {
              "name": "pv",
              "value": "DA4DFE71_7801",
              "path": "/",
              "domain": "demo.docusign.net",
              "expires": "1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z",
              "httpOnly": true,
              "secure": true,
              "sameSite": "None"
            },
            {
              "name": "ssid",
              "value": "deg4dob3hltz3vzaefbvqjim",
              "path": "/",
              "domain": "demo.docusign.net",
              "expires": "1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z",
              "httpOnly": true,
              "secure": true,
              "sameSite": "None"
            },
            {
              "name": "MemberConsoleMobile",
              "value": "",
              "path": "/",
              "domain": "demo.docusign.net",
              "expires": "1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z",
              "httpOnly": false,
              "secure": true,
              "sameSite": "None"
            },
            {
              "name": "__RequestVerificationToken_L1NpZ25pbmc1",
              "value": "AUg7xNmdsECMOXs8jueYqMkB0",
              "path": "/",
              "domain": "demo.docusign.net",
              "expires": "1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z",
              "httpOnly": true,
              "secure": true,
              "sameSite": "None"
            },
            {
              "name": "DSSessionAttributes",
              "value": "EnvelopeId:7addcbc5-ffb4-4a25-a7f2-e092fc4f73ca,SenderAccountId:0a060a89-b542-4301-90b4-d45c7d5ef06e,RecipientAccountId:cccccccc-cccc-cccc-cccc-cccccccccccc,RecipientId:0e8a037b-5627-41d7-a5f5-9b2fa47b6e40",
              "path": "/",
              "domain": "demo.docusign.net",
              "expires": "1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z",
              "httpOnly": true,
              "secure": true,
              "sameSite": "None"
            }
          ],
          "headersSize": 1309,
          "bodySize": 0
        },
        "response": {
          "status": 200,
          "statusText": "OK",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Length",
              "value": "138926"
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Type",
              "value": "image/gif"
            },
            {
              "name": "Date",
              "value": "Tue, 12 Mar 2024 18:11:07 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "Referrer-Policy",
              "value": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
            },
            {
              "name": "Set-Cookie",
              "value": "pv=DA4DFE71_7801; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None"
            },
            {
              "name": "Strict-Transport-Security",
              "value": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
            },
            {
              "name": "X-Content-Type-Options",
              "value": "nosniff"
            },
            {
              "name": "X-DocuSign-Node",
              "value": "DA4DFE71"
            },
            {
              "name": "X-XSS-Protection",
              "value": "1; mode=block"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [
            {
              "name": "pv",
              "value": "DA4DFE71_7801",
              "path": "/",
              "domain": "demo.docusign.net",
              "expires": null,
              "httpOnly": true,
              "secure": true,
              "sameSite": "None"
            }
          ],
          "content": {
            "size": 138926,
            "mimeType": "image/gif",
            "compression": 0,
            "text": "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.......(very long)
```

The console logs also:
[image: console screenshot]

Comment: Can you look at the [HAR file](https://www.google.com/search?q=har+file) to see what API calls are happening/hanging? Then add the info to your question. **Also,** what Inspector/Console errors, if any, are being logged. **Lastly** what framework are you using? React? Which version. Thank you

Comment: Added relevent HAR info, it looks to me like it's working as expected. Sent Console errors also. Re: framework: I'm using elm-pages, which is written in elm, a functional language that compiles to javascript. It uses custom elements as a method to embed javascript components. https://elm-pages.com, https://elm-lang.org, https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/custom_elements

Comment: It's pretty close to working -- when i load the page, i get an email as the document creator notifying me that the document was viewed. The page just isn't showing the document

Comment: Looking at the console errors, wondering if this is same issue: https://community.docusign.com/apis-and-sdks-60/permission-policy-violation-for-geolocation-access-when-using-docusign-js-2686

Comment: For what it's worth, when instead of trying to embed the focused view on the page, I just put the link directly, so it can be clicked on, the link works and you can sign the document just fine. So whatever is going has to do with how I'm trying to embed the document within my page.

Answer (score 1):

Focused view library does search for the iframe where the envelope is loaded after mounting on screen. As you are registering it as a shadow root this cannot be found. I was able to find a solution for that removing the shadow root usage and registering it as a regular DOM element.

- Removed the **this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })** from constructor
- Changed **this.shadowRoot** declarations to use only **this**
- Provided agreementDiv to the **signing.mount** method

One side suggestion is to remove **this.render()** from **attributeChangedCallback** because this makes the component to re-render and invalidates the generated link (as embedded signing links can only be used once and trying to re-use a link that was previously accessed will throw another infinite spinning loading in side the loaded div).

Please check if this works for you! ;D